# Have user pick app-widget within app (not via android widget menu)

Tags: android, android-widget

I current have 3 widget providers with different sizes. The user can see the 3 options in the android widget screen. However, I keep getting bad feedback because users pick the smaller size  when they want the larger size even though I have them labeled.

So, my question is this. Can I have a (1) widget setup in the android menu that when selected prompts the user which widget size or provider to use? It would then continue on to the configuration screen with the user selected widget size (1x4, 1x2, 2x2).

I know this is possible in some way. Some phone vendors combine widget providers in the main widget screen and then present the user with a "sub-widget" screen. I also have seen apps do this I think...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, sorry, unless you are implementing an AppWidgetHost - not a usual task for a normal application. See my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18474349/858626.

What you have seen from some phone vendors are features of custom launchers. Normally only apps from those same vendors are the ones that can take advantage of such advanced features.