# Sending Intent to Home and Widget Add

Tags: android, widget, homescreen

I'm trying to figure out how to send an intent to the home screen to add a Widget to it if I can. Any ideas? Here is some code I've been fooling around with to at least prompt the Add Widget selection.

```
AppWidgetManager mAppWidgetManager;
AppWidgetHost mAppWidgetHost;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    selectWidget();

    mAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
    mAppWidgetHost = new AppWidgetHost(this, R.id.APPWIDGET_HOST_ID);
}

void selectWidget() {
    int appWidgetId = this.mAppWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();
    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK);
    pickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    startActivityForResult(pickIntent, R.id.REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET);
}
```

Thank you to anybody who contributes.

Comment: There are thousands of home screen implementations. Few of those support app widgets.

Comment: Can you expand on what you're trying to accomplish, and what did you get with this code until now?

Comment: @Jose_GD Currently the code just simply displays the list of widgets to add, However thats it. What im trying to accomplish is to add a widget to the home screen upon click. So i want to be within my app, launch intent to home screen then display list of widgets to then click and hold to place to the homescreen. Im unsure on if this is possible with the current android api's

Comment: @JaisonBrooks you're trying to achieve the same thing I'm trying now. I guess I have an answer, will post it soon. BTW your selectWidget() call on onCreate() should be the last sentence there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send the ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK intent to the system, but your app cannot process it, unless what you're coding is a Home screen replacement, i.e. a launcher.

Take a look at the documentation for [App Widget Host](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/host.html), in particular the section about [Host Binding](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/host.html#host-binding). The code you're using in the `selectWidget()` method is the same used in the original Launcher app (under title *Binding app widgets on Android 4.0 and lower*). Then comes an implementation for `onActivityResult`, where the intent is processed. This method is what is missing in your code, but if you include it, you will end up doing all the work the Home screen app does (see `addAppWidget(Intent data)` next in that page).

If you continue reading the App Widget Host doc, you will see that the binding process changed on Android 4.1 and there is also a new intent for this task that requires a permission in the manifest. And to complicate things more, keep in mind @CommonsWare's comment: there are a lot of Home screen implementations, that probably do the binding process differently :(

To summarize: there's no way to get the list of app widgets **and** process what the user selected, neither is a way to ask the launcher app to do this for us, unfortunately. Perhaps in a future Android version, as this comment in the [latest Launcher source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/master/src/com/android/launcher2/InstallWidgetReceiver.java) reveals:

> /**
>   We will likely flesh this out later, to handle allow external apps to place widgets, but for now,
>   we just want to expose the action around for checking elsewhere.  */

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing thing all up for me. I sincerely appreciate you helping me understand this better.

Comment: You're welcome. What is funny is that I answered a similar question some time ago and now I answered yours while researching about the possibility of launching the picker from an activity... :)